# Create numeric samples based on multiple conditions of multiple vectors

Tags: r, dplyr, sampling

Given the following data frame:

```r
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~pass_id, ~km_ini, ~km_fin,
        1L,    0.89,    2.39,
        2L,    1.53,    3.03,
        3L,    21.9,    23.4,
        4L,    23.4,    24.9,
        5L,      24,    25.5,
        6L,    25.9,    27.4,
        7L,    36.7,    38.2,
        8L,    41.4,    42.9,
        9L,    42.1,    43.6,
       10L,    45.5,      47
  )
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I need a sample of any 50 numbers that match the **all** following criteria for **all the rows** of `df`:

1. `>= .750`
2. `<= 99.450`
3. `< km_ini - .750`
4. `> km_fin + .750`

My best shot is far away from what I am expecting. First I did a `runif`, then I `enframe`d it, and tried to `filter`, but I just got it working for the first two conditions. Anyway, I don't necessarily need the result as a data frame, it could be a numeric vector.

```r
library(tidyverse, verbose = F)

set.seed(42)
sort(runif(100000, 0, 99.450)) %>% 
  enframe(., "ID", "km") %>% 
  filter(km >= .750 & km <= 99.450 - .750)
#> # A tibble: 98,467 x 2
#>       ID    km
#>    <int> <dbl>
#>  1   763 0.750
#>  2   764 0.751
#>  3   765 0.751
#>  4   766 0.753
#>  5   767 0.753
#>  6   768 0.754
#>  7   769 0.754
#>  8   770 0.755
#>  9   771 0.755
#> 10   772 0.757
#> # … with 98,457 more rows
```

**EDIT: trying to visually display the problem**

The final result needs to be a numerical vector (or df) that assesses the entire data set, not just each row separately. As an example for the first two lines, see the following representation:

[image]

So, see that:

- The black line indicates that I cannot have data smaller than .750.
- The blue line indicates where I cannot have records due to the coverage area of km_ini and km_fin (arrows) of line 1 and one more appendix considering the area of + or - .750 (between the arrows and the points).
- The red line indicates where I cannot have records due to the coverage area of km_ini and km_fin (arrows) of line 2 and another appendix considering the area of + or - .750 (between the arrows and the points).

This way, right away, the random set of data within the first 4000 meters, could only have numbers from 3030 + .750.

The question, then, is to try to do this programmatically so that all lines of the data frame are evaluated and the numbers generated are not within all the conditions mentioned.

Comment: May be you need `map2` i.e. `map2(df$km_ini, d$km_fin, ~ sort(runif(100000, 0, 99.450)) %>% 
  enframe(., "ID", "km") %>% filter(km > .750, km <= 99.450 - .750, km <.x - .750, km > .y + .750))`

Comment: @akrun, unfortunately it didn't work. It resulted in ten empty lists. I don't necessarily need it in data frame, I can just have a vector of 50 values. I'll add this info to the question.

Comment: You've said that the numbers should satisfy `< km_ini - .750` and `> km_fin + .750`. Is that a typo because from what I can see, `km_ini < km_fin`.

Comment: Also, do you want 50 samples for each line of your df?

Comment: I made a graphical representation trying to better explain the problem. This case is a road that I need to process some analyses and it can't be within a buffer distance of some structures (from km_ini to km_fin). The perfect option would be having all the numbers that fit the requisites because from these results I will have to filter those that are not within a radius of .750 m (1500 m total distance/diameter). I suppose 50 is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I understand. You want to sample in the gaps delimited by the distances, with the complicating factor that you cannot sample on either side of the marked distances for 750m.

I think it is useful to get a clearer visual understanding of the problem. In this plot, the x axis represents distance (the y axis is just a "dummy" axis, since we are only interested in the x axis). The black bars are the "exclusion zones" in which we cannot sample. There are also 750m zones on either side of the exclusion zones in which we do not want to sample, which are here coloured red:

[image]

So essentially, we want a uniform sample from the non-shaded areas of the x axis in this plot.

My solution is to first merge the overlapping segments, then create a sample space that is weighted according to the size of each gap and take 50 uniform samples from that space.

Here, I have generalized to allow arbitrary limits and sample size.

```r
sample_space <- function(km_ini, km_fin, km_max = 99.45, buffer = 0.75, n = 50)
{
  # Find and merge overlaps
  i <- 1
  km_ini <- km_ini - buffer
  km_fin <- km_fin + buffer
  while(i <= length(km_ini))
  {
    overlaps <- which(km_ini < km_fin[i] & km_fin > km_ini[i])
    if(length(overlaps) < 2) {i <- i + 1; next;}
    km_ini <- c(km_ini, min(km_ini[overlaps]))
    km_fin <- c(km_fin, max(km_fin[overlaps]))
    km_ini <- km_ini[-overlaps]
    km_fin <- km_fin[-overlaps]
    i <- 1
  }

  # Create a matrix of appropriate gaps
  gaps <- cbind(sort(km_fin), c(sort(km_ini)[-1], km_max))

  print(gaps)
  # Create a weighted sample space
  splits <- c(0, cumsum(apply(gaps, 1, diff)))

  # Take a sample within that space
  runifs <- runif(n, 0, max(splits))

  # Add the appropriate starting value back on
  index <- as.numeric(cut(runifs, splits))
  runifs - splits[index] + gaps[index, 1]
}
```

So now we can do

```r
sample_space(df$km_ini, df$km_fin)
#>  [1] 93.107858 92.216660 83.597703 86.341198 72.258245 86.591883 18.572744
#>  [8] 16.641163 73.344658 73.075426 78.230074 97.745802 52.654342 52.298444
#> [15] 70.029034 67.430346 95.328900 62.250864 79.144025 86.344868  7.063474
#> [22] 58.797335 79.304272 54.731057 32.137068 84.837576 94.226992 50.808135
#> [29] 65.987277 76.666933 29.225744 33.309866 13.013735  6.925277 65.207383
#> [36] 91.591293 61.614993 18.646062 97.550237 48.478875 12.860920 20.263471
#> [43] 34.980616 50.583291 15.813562 96.104448 91.310377 53.063613 17.376281
#> [50] 72.511153
```

To show that this does what we wanted it to, let's plot the sample over the plot of exclusion zones:

```r
set.seed(69)
sample_df <- data.frame(x = sample_space(df$km_ini, df$km_fin),
                      y = runif(50, 0.45, 0.55))

ggplot(df) + 
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = km_ini - 0.75, xmax = km_fin + 0.75, ymin = 0, ymax = 1), 
            alpha = 0.5, fill = "red") +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = km_ini, xmax = km_fin, ymin = 0, ymax = 1), fill = "black") +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 0, xmax = 0.75, ymin = 0, ymax = 1), alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 99.45, xmax = 100, ymin = 0, ymax = 1), alpha = 0.5) +
  labs(x = "distance", y = "dummy") +
  geom_point(data = sample_df, aes(x = x, y = y), col = "blue")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Firstly, thank you and I beg your pardon for maybe not being so clear on my explanation (English is not my birth language). I think you are near the result, but I can't evaluate why it is not. I need that the numbers are processed by row, but also for each row considering the data frame as a whole. In your example, we got 47.28 in sample 6, but it is not greater .750 than 47 (km_fin of pass_id #10) and 21.94 in sample 5 also doesn't match the criteria of pass_id #3, because it is not lesser than km_ini +.750 neither greater than km_fin + .750 . Is it a little bit clear now?

Comment: @rdornas In that case, aren't you just looking for `runif(50, max(df$km_fin) + 0.75, 99.45)`?

Comment: In a certain point you are totally right. My bad, the df sample I gave was half of actual df, thats why it works, because I would have more than 50 km after the 47 (`max(df$km_fin)`). But imagine instead of 99.45 I restrict it to 50. If I process the code in your comment above it would give me 50 numbers between 47 and 50, although I expect to have numbers spread all over.

Comment: @rdornas so you are looking to sample the "gaps"?

Comment: Kind of! You gave me an insight. I could maybe calculate a `case_when(km_fin + .750 > lead(km_ini - .750) ~ as.double(NA_integer_), TRUE ~ lead(km_ini) - km_fin)` to find the gaps. If the gaps are `> 1.5` they could be available for sampling. It still is not a programmatically way but it is near of what I need and I am capable to do.

Comment: @rdornas I have changed my answer to take account of your updated description. Please see if this checks out.

Comment: This is awesome!! A huge thank you! Just as a note, I made a test transforming your function to `function(km_ini, km_fin, km_max, buffer, samples)`. This way I can set also the `km_max` (in this case was 99.45), the `buffer` (in this case was .750) and the n of `samples` (in this case was 50). Can I change it in your answer or you change it?

Comment: @rdornas I have updated to allow arbitrary inputs, and have also added plots to giver a better visual intuition of the problem and solution.